# Difference in behavior while using friend function and normal public function

Tags: c++, friend

Why do I get different results for the following two cases? I am passing by value in both cases.

Case1: using public member function: (output: 2:1)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class one {
  int hrs; int mins;
public:
  void in(int h, int m)
  { hrs = h; mins = m; }
  friend void dis(one);
};

void dis(one objone)
{ cout << objone.hrs <<":"<< objone.mins << endl; }

int main ()
{
  one obj1;
  obj1.in(2, 1);
  dis(obj1);
  return 0;
}
```

Case2: using friend function. (output:-20704:32763)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class one
{
  int hrs; int mins;
  friend void in(one);
  friend void dis(one);
};

void in(one objone)
{ objone.hrs = 2; objone.mins=1; }

void dis(one objone)
{ cout << objone.hrs <<":"<< objone.mins << endl; }

int main ()
{
  one obj1;
  in(obj1);
  dis(obj1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because when you pass `obj1` to `in()` you are sending a copy of the object as parameter, not the actual `obj1`, so your objects' internal fields do not get modified. Try to pass `obj1` by reference.

Comment: fair point, but even in the first case, I am passing by value and thereby it shall be working on copies only right?

Comment: True, in the first case you are passing by value too, but the integers 1 and 2 are passed by value, whose values get caught and assigned to the internal fields of the `obj1` object. However, in the seconds case, the one passed by value is `obj1`. So this time the internal fields of the copy of `obj1` get modified, not those of the actual object. Changing the method prototype to `friend void in(one&)` and `void in(one& one)` should get it working right.

Comment: yes, I do agree if i pass by ref I should get it right, but I was just curious why I had different results.Thanks, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say, because you pass by value you are not passing the same object to the function

```
In(one obj)
```

Will call the constructor of object `one` and hence will not have its internal members initialised. Pass by reference to solve your problem

```
In(one & obj)
```